# Create Table Loop to display records Web2Py / SQLFORM

Tags: html, sql, web2py

I am a recent college grad trying to build a bigger portfolio so I am building a fake e-commerce site.  I want to build a html table that takes in data from SQLFORM query.

For example, if I have 8 entries / and i want 3 columns - it displays as so.

X X X

X X X

X X

And if i have only 4 entries / and i want 3 columns - it displays as so..

X X X

X

I am having trouble figuring this out... I could not find any resources on web2py online that demonstrate this.  Here is my current code to display 1 column... and 1 record per row.  In my code the =thenumber is the number of records that are generated by the query.

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h1>Disc Golf Post</h1>
</hr>
{{=thenumber}}
{{ for x in rows: }}
<div class='row'>
    <img  class='col col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12' src='http://127.0.0.1:8000/pluralsight/static{{=x.products_image}}' alt='blog image' />
    <div class='col col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
        <p class='lead'>
            <b>{{=x.products_title}}</b>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>Category: </b>{{=x.products_manufacturer}}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{=x.products_price}}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{=x.products_capacity}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
{{pass}}
```

I am aware I need to do some formatting issues on size of columns and such.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated or a link to a site that details this in web2py would also be fantastic.  Thanks in advance.